# How to split StartDateTime field of Activity event

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image][image]How to split StartDateTime field of Activity event object in Visual force page i tried to retrieve it with inputfield but i can find single box but not as the standard style of the field.

Comment: rakesh please post screen shot and your code ?

Comment: hi Mohith i add screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split a Datetime field into its constituents, you can use [Datetime instance methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm)

You can also get the Hour, Minute and Seconds part of the time as separate strings.

```
Datetime nowTime = Datetime.now();
String DateStr = String.valueOf(nowTime.date());
String timeStr = String.valueOf(nowTime.time());

System.debug(DateStr + ' : ' + timeStr);
```

To render a Datetime field in Visualforce, you need to bake your own field to display the date and time components separately, there isn't a native field type that you can use to display like it is on the Task Edit Screen. (i.e. a Time Picker like there is a Date Picker)

You can render this as field, one an inputField of type Date, which allows you to pick the date in a calendar.

For the time, render a selectList, with selectOptions to represent the time (08:00, 08:30,....)

Here is an example of how you could render a selectList for the time part.

```
 public SelectOption[] getReminderTimeList() 
        {   
            TaskReminderTime = '09:00';
            SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[]{};
            String mins = '30';
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 48; i++) 
            {
                mins        = (mins == '30') ? '00' : '30';
                Integer hrs = ((i*30) / 60);
                String hr   = (string.valueOf(hrs).length() == 1) ? '0' + string.valueOf(hrs) : string.valueOf(hrs);            

                String key = hr + ':' + mins;

                options.add(new SelectOption(key, key));
            }
            return options;   
        }
```

Comment: very nice loop for the time selectList. although i love a good ternary :) , here is a little trick i picked up a while back for working with date / time components that is now possible in apex with the new string methods: `String hr   = ('0'+(string.valueOf(hrs))).right(2);` will always give you a 2-digit component. a bit cleaner maybe?